# Calling Oracle User defined function in Hibernate HQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

Can anyone help me here. I want to call an oracle function in Spring+hibernate application.
How this can be done.

Eg: Oracle Function olddata(Varchar2 serialNumber)
This returns set of records having xyz fields. I need to call this function in hibernate using HQL. Also, the function have 2 tables in it using join and records are fetched from both these tables.

Regards,
Parichaya

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](http://keyurj.blogspot.com/2012/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html) blog exactly describes what you need. (Basically you need to create your own Hibernate dialect - which sounds scary at first but not a big deal actually).